# How to apply a unique constraint across multiple hierarchy levels

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have tables with the following layout:

- A `Project` can have many `Entity` relationships.
- An `Entity` can have many `DataPoint` relationships.

How can I enforce that the `Name` column of the `DataPoint` table must be unique per ***project***?

Currently, I have a foreign key in `Entity` for the project and another foreign key in `DataPoint` for the entity. I thought about adding the ProjectId as another foreign key column in the `DataPoint` table so that I could create a unique constraint using `DataPoint.ProjectId, DataPoint.Name`, but that would introduce a new problem of not being able to guarantee that DataPoint.EntityId is actually a child of DataPoint.ProjectId.

Comment: I don't think you need such hierarchical constraints in your database, and I could argue that the need for such conatraints implies bad application logic.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I wish you hadn't deleted your answer. It got me thinking, couldn't I have a composite foreign key using ProjectId and EntityId from `DataPoint` to `Entity`? That would allow the unique constraint _and also_ guarantee that the project/entity pair is valid, would it not?

Comment: This is over my head :-( ... someone else will hopefully answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to prevent two entities pointing to the same project from having the same data points.  This is not directly supported by SQL constraints, which means that triggers are one solution.

You can effectively do the same thing, if you can incur a bit of extra overhead:  include the `projectid` in `datapoint`.  Then include the following constraints:

```
 constraint foreign key (projectid, entityid) refers to entities(projectid, entityid);

constraint unique (projectid, name);
```

The first constraint is redundant (`projectid` is not needed), but there is little harm with it.  The biggest issue is that you need to include the `projectid` in `datapoint` -- and remember to insert it.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if the composite foreign key needs to refer to a composite primary key? I think I read somewhere that composite foreign keys need either a composite PK or UC in the parent table. Are you able to confirm?